# How can I stop Flutter from jumping to the first route whenever I save changes?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am developing a flutter app with Firebase as the back-end. The challenge I am facing is that whenever I make any changes and save, the hot reload causes the app to go back to its first route.

My pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.1
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  firebase_database: ^7.2.1
  firebase_storage: ^10.0.3
  provider: ^6.0.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

My navigator is:

```
         onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => SignIn()));
          },
```

This causes problems as I have to keep navigating back to the page I am editing every time I save. Does anyone know how I can resolve this.

Comment: Please try unit testing and integration test before

Comment: Hi,  at what point would I have to do the test? Everything else is working well, until I save.

Comment: Whenever you write a function or create a new widget. Just write the test. It will save time because for testing each feature you do not need to build and run on emulator.